# Pass environment variables to child process kicked off by rsyslog omprog module

Tags: rsyslog

I have defined a program to handle logs via the omprog module in the rsyslog file as follows:

```
module(load="omprog")
if $programname == 'myprogram' and getenv('ENV_FOO') == 'foo_value' then {
    action(type="omprog" binary="/pathto/my_log_handler.py")
}
```

I have verified that rsyslog inherits the environment variable ENV_FOO and kicks off the binary but the child process running my_log_handler.py does not seem to inherit the environment variables. I have tested that including the following snippet in my_log_handler.py correctly prints 'foo_value' when run from the shell but prints nothing when triggered by rsyslog's omprog module.

```
print(os.environ['ENV_FOO'])
```

Is there a way to have the binary triggered by rsyslog's omprog module inherit the environment variables of rsyslog?

Answer (score 1):

This was [added in rsyslog v8.38](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/2921) (i.e., from that version on, the environment is passed to the child process).